# Databinding to model, with custom validation attributes - when to bind & validate?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm a bit new to WinForms databinding & custom validation.

Say I have a simple model in my domain:

```
public class SecurityObject
{

    [StringLength(25)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool HasAccess { get; set; }
}
```

The Name property is data-bound to a TextBox. I would like apply the custom attribute validation so I can show a ToolTip when the validation is violated. (NOTE: yes I know I can set the MaximumLength property on the textbox, and plan to, but this is not my question right now.)

My question is, at what point should be validation be triggered?

1. Doesn't seem like it can be triggered in TextBox_Validating(..), because at that point, the new value hasn't bee written back to the model.
2. It could be triggered at TextBox_Validated(..) because the value has been written back to the model by then. However this seems inappropriate because the TextBox thinks it is valid, while the model it's bound to is not - seems fishy to me.
3. I guess you could disable the automatic binding, then trigger it manually within TextBox_Validating(...) by calling DataBinding.WriteValue(...) - but this seems a shame to go to so much extra effort and defeats half the point of data binding in the first place.

So, what is the recommended way to run model validation when databound?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: OK thanks. will remember next time

Answer (score 0):

IMO the validating event is where validation should be happening.

> Doesn't seem like it can be triggered in TextBox_Validating(..), because at that point, the new value hasn't bee written back to the model.

Doesn't matter if the value has actually been set in the model, does it? What about this:

```
ValidationContext vc = new ValidationContext(myEntity, null, null);
vc.MemberName = "myProperty";
Boolean isValid = Validator.TryValidateProperty(formPropertyValue, vc, null);
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius. Shanksh